# How to change ctypes field size in class [python]?

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

I'm trying to parse input packets from network with python.

For do that i created simple class:

```
class S2C_ChallengePacket(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [
    ("type", ctypes.c_byte),
    ("sessionid", ctypes.c_byte * 4),
    ("challenge", ctypes.c_wchar_p)]
```

Field "challenge" it's null-terminated string and it has a variable (changeable) size. So i added *pack* variable to my S2C_ChallengePacket class.

[Python's documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Structure._pack_):

> *pack* An optional small integer that allows to override the alignment of structure fields in the instance. *pack* must already be defined when *fields* is assigned, otherwise it will have no effect.

But, If i try refer to "challenge" field i get a "Segmentation fault" error.

```
packet = QueryPacket.S2C_ChallengePacket.from_buffer_copy(data)
print packet.challenge <--- "Segmentation fault" here
```

Comment: Are you sure pack is doing what you think it is doing?  Can you give an example of your data?

Comment: Example here http://wiki.vg/Query#Response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `c_wchar_p` is a pointer, so that won't work. This would be easier using the struct module:

```
>>> base_size = struct.calcsize('>BI')
>>> response = b'\x09\x00\x00\x00\x019513307\x00'
>>> response = response[:-1] # remove null
>>> token_len = len(response) - base_size
>>> struct.unpack('>BI%ds' % token_len, response)
(9, 1, b'9513307')
```